# Unable to import module 'lambda_function':

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I am trying to test my python code on AWS Lambda I am getting the following error.

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lambda_function'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "stackTrace": []
}
```

These are the basic Setup steps which I followed to push my code into AWS Lambda:-

- First rename your main.py file as 'lambda_function.py'
- Change the name of your 'main' function to 'def lambda_handler():'
- ZIP the File
- Go to AWS Lambda Console, Create Function.
- Provide the FunctionName - 'Demo'
- Choose Python 3.9 Runtime (or 3.7/3.8)
- Let the architecture be 'x86_64'
- Rest configurations be acceptable. Hit the 'Create Function' Button
- There will be a tab/dropdown named 'Upload From'
- Choose the .zip File
- Upload the File
- Click on the 'Test Button'
- Click the configure test event.
- Provide the event name as 'Test'
- Clear the JSON Values and provide empty JSON- {}
- Save it.
- Test the Lambda Function

But after doing this I am getting this error

```
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lambda_function'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
```

I have made sure to check my [Handler Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7L05.png).

My code - Here I am trying to invoke execute_AWS_TF() function using lambda_handler()

```
import connect_mongoDB

def lambda_handler():
    connect_mongoDB.execute_AMS_TF()
```

Working tree:

[image]

Directory Structure of my zip File:

[image]

Comment: What is your directory structure of your deployment zip file.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I have added the directory structure of my deployment zip file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lambda_function.py` is in a subfolder called `AWS_REPORT...`. So you have the tell that to aws. The hendler info should be:

```
AWS_REPORT.../lambda_function.lambda_handler
```

Off course `AWS_REPORT...` must be replaced by the actual name.